# Eclipse: How to substitute strings in files copied to output folder

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, string-substitution, keyword-substitution

Eclipse copies files which are not Java sources to output folder as-is. I need to pre-process (substitute variables) these files before they are copied. The substitution table shall be project-based.

Ideally, maven2 properties shall be used as the substitution table.

Answer (score 0):

m2eclipse plugin for eclipse handles maven2 properties well.